# How to send http header for basic authentification when cloning with git lfs

Tags: git, powershell, gitlab, git-lfs

Hi everyone i migrated a GitLab repo to start using GIT LFS. when you start using GIT LFS for cloning your repositories you must use HTTPS to every request you do (clone, pull, push)

in my case we have enable the two factor authentication that means that we need to send our username and the PAT (personal access token) on every request.

So for doing that I'm doing this in this way:

I get the base64 authentication header

```
$auth_basic = [Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("PlatinumDeployToken:asdasdLg9VVxBEzPp"))
```

and then I send the clone request in this way:

```
git lfs clone -c http.extraheader="AUTHORIZATION: basic $auth_basic" https://gitlab.inside.com/Platinum/TRXN_LFS.git "C:\testheaders" --branch "PRODUCTION"
```

the problem when doing this way I got this error:

LFS: Client error: https://gitlab.inside.com/Platinum/TRXN_LFS.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/d2f34058e9c225e94164008735227d5a97b200507da79bb58a4e60e3b098707b

on every binaries file that tries to download.

when enable degug to see what its happened

```
$env:GIT_TRACE=1
$env:GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1
$env:GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1
```

I got this response:

```
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 150
< Content-Type: text/html
< Date: Wed, 10 Nov 2021 16:17:34 GMT
< Server: nginx
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=16070400; includeSubDomains
<
10:17:34.399534 trace git-lfs: xfer: adapter "basic" worker 0 finished job for "917a77065de94661f6997d8d301db30130033670b7d5d9c00a212904f393a00f"
10:17:34.400529 trace git-lfs: xfer: adapter "basic" worker 0 processing job for "6559abdbd7e5c21cef28c12f2b5a45b395c73fd55a03b05a5ce8b59cd749a0cd"
10:17:34.399534 trace git-lfs: tq: refusing to retry "917a77065de94661f6997d8d301db30130033670b7d5d9c00a212904f393a00f", too many retries (8)
10:17:34.400529 trace git-lfs: tq: refusing to retry "917a77065de94661f6997d8d301db30130033670b7d5d9c00a212904f393a00f", too many retries (8)
10:17:34.410502 trace git-lfs: HTTP: GET https://gitlab.inside.com/Platinum/TRXN_LFS.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/6559abdbd7e5c21cef28c12f2b5a45b395c73fd55a03b05a5ce8b59cd749a0cd
> GET /Platinum/TRXN_LFS.git/gitlab-lfs/objects/6559abdbd7e5c21cef28c12f2b5a45b395c73fd55a03b05a5ce8b59cd749a0cd HTTP/1.1
> Host: gitlab.inside.com
> Authorization: Basic * * * * *
> Authorization: Basic * * * * *
> User-Agent: git-lfs/2.13.2 (GitHub; windows amd64; go 1.14.13; git fc664697)
>
10:17:35.054339 trace git-lfs: HTTP: 400
```

it seen that i got an 400 response because git lfs sent a duplicate authentication header.

Does anyone knows if this its the correct way to do it. or how can i fix this issue?

Regars.

Comment: Have you tried using ssh to clone your repos? The ssh client should send the HTTP basic auth for LFS objects for you in the correct manner without any special configuration... it should _just work_.

Answer (score 0):

When you clone a repository with Git LFS, the best way to handle credentials is to use a credential helper.  That's because Git and Git LFS use the same mechanisms to handle credentials.  The [Git FAQ has an entry](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials) on how to do this.  While the Git FAQ talks about a password, you'll want to use your token instead of a password in this case.

Note that while you *can* use `http.extraheader` in this case, it's not recommended for that purpose, and when you do so, everyone on the system can see your credentials, which isn't secure.  Therefore, you should avoid doing so.

In your particular case, you ended up with a problem because either you already have a credential helper configured and it sent another header, or because, as part of the Git LFS protocol, your Git LFS client was told to use a different token specific to that object, and both got sent.  That's another reason you should avoid `http.extraheader` here and just use a credential helper.